# Solving a system of Pell and Pell-like equations

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve (*Find all the solutions, if there are, or prove there are not*)  the system of 2 Pell or Pell-like simultanous equations over the positive integers :

$2b^{2}= a^{2} +1 = 3k^{2} + 2 $ with the 3 variables (a,b,k).

Note that the 2 equations are :
 $a^{2} -2b^{2} = -1$ and  $a^{2} -3k^{2} = 1$
The third one: $ 2b^{2} -3k^{2} =2$ does not need to be solved if the other two are.

Comment: there is $(a,b,k) = (7,5,4)$, and I would be surprised if there was any other solution.

Comment: Yes mercio (7,5,4) is a solution. Try to find more or prove there are not any more.

Answer (score 2):

László Szalay, On the resolution of simultaneous Pell equations, Annales Mathematicae et Informaticae 34 (2007) pp. 77–87, is available [here](http://ami.ektf.hu/uploads/papers/finalpdf/AMI_34_from77to87.pdf). I don't know whether the precise pair of equations you give is discussed in the paper, but it does give you the tools and references you need to approach this kind of problem.

EDIT: Having looked a bit more closely at the paper, I believe a solution to your problem is in fact given in the paper and attributed to Riele, reference 24.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the simultanous
$$
\begin{align}3x^2−y^2=2\tag{1}\\8x^2−z^2=7\tag{2}\end{align}
$$
$$
x_{n+1}=2x_n+y_n\quad\text{and}\quad y_{n+1}=3x_n+2y_n
$$
for $(1)$ and
$$
x_{n+1}=3x_n+z_n\quad\text{and}\quad z_{n+1}=8x_n+3z_n
$$
for $(2)$. And we get: $(1)\Rightarrow(x,y)=(1,1);(3,5);(11,19);(41,71);(153,265);(571,989)$ and $(2)\Rightarrow(x,z)=(−1,1);(2,5);(11,31);(64,181);(373,1055);(2174,6149)$. The solutions coincide in the same $n^{\text{th}}$ position, the third position: for the only solution $(x,y,z) = (11,19,31)$.

Clearly, x grows faster, after its values coincide, permanently in (2) than in (1), and thus we prove this is the only non trivial solution. The case (2) has another family of solutions : $(1,1);(4,11);(23,65);(134,379)$ which obviously still grow faster, beginning with a higher value of one of its initial terms and will never give a solution.

Comment: Please use LaTeX to make the math readable. [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is the LaTeX interface supported here.

Comment: This is not an answer as it does not prove that there might not be further solutions.

Comment: This proves clearly the unicity of the non trivial solution. And i seldom use TeX cause i am a militant for a simplification of the "notation" and the "naming" of mathematics. I do prefer the quite correct and exact and simpler ASCII. How maths is written (drawn; in fact) does not alter its truth.

Comment: Although your *examples* indicate that the $x_n$ from $(2)$ grow faster than those from $(1)$, this is not a proof of that fact. However, even after that fact is established, why is it not possible that $x_{n_1}$ from $(1)$ might equal $x_{n_2}$ from $(2)$ for two *different* indices $n_1$ and $n_2$?

Comment: Although the truth of the math is the unchanged no matter how it is written, it is part of the purpose of this site to allow these truths to be understood by those who wish to understand them. In this function, making the math easier to read makes it easier to understand.

Comment: "Insanity is repeating the same mistakes and expecting different results."

Comment: I never married you; Gerry on the hill; by the way, who on earth super are you or do you believe you are? Do you really  think you can beat a true pure Spaniard and amateur ?

Comment: PS: For the sake of all those nice people out there -if there still are in the USA or in the english speaking countries- i stumbled upon this site with no particular purpose, by pure chance from my part (just wondering what the chances of alter parts were to induce my chance to be here); i´ll go if some of the people belonging to this site do not behave better and apologize, for rich of gold we are not but pride and fair and honour we do have.

Answer (score -1):

$a^2 - 3*k^2 = 1$ (1) , general solution:

$a(n+1) = 2a(n) + 3k(n)$, $k(n+1) = a(n) + 2k(n)$. The first 6 solutions, without counting the  trivial solution: (1,0) are:
$(a,k) = (2,1); (7,4); (26,15); (97,56); (362,209); (1351,780);\dots$

$a^2 - 2*b^2 = -1$ (2), general solution:

$a(n+1) = 3a(n) + 4b(n)$, $b(n+1) = 2a(n) + 3b(n)$. The first 6 solutions are:
$(a,b) = (1,1); (7,5); (41,29); (239,169); (1393,985); (8119,5741);\dots$

Once we match the same a value in both equations: a=7 asociated to k=4 and b=5; we do not need to look any  more for solutions, since both a and b grow faster in one equation than a and k in the other ---> the only solution non trivial is (a,b,k) = (7,5,4). The problem would be if a(n) grew faster and b(n) slower in one equation than in the other, or the contrary. In that case we would have to match another coincident value of "a" among the infinite values in both equations. But no problem here.

The general solution of the third equation $2b^{2} -3k^{2} = 2$ is $b(n+1) = 5b(n)+ 6k(n) ; k(n+1) = 4b(n) + 5k(n)$ with solutions: $(1,0);(5,4);(49,40);(485,396);(4801,3920), ...$

Comment: This is not a valid argument, as for all you know the 794th $a$-value from the first equation equals the 538th $a$-value from the second equation, and that would give you another solution to the pair of equations. Please look at the paper to which I linked in my answer to see what one has to do to solve this kind of system of equations. Also, if you are going to make regular use of this website, it would be good if you would learn something about formatting mathematics here.

Comment: There are three equations; not only two. The third one with variables b and k links b to k in the position shown in my very-easy-to-find solutions. n-th solution of first equation has to be compared with the same-and only- n-th in the second one. You do not need any algorithm in this case. You´re wrong mister Myerson.

Comment: Please try to take a more civil tone on this website.  Not only this *not* an answer, but your entire comment amounts to repeating your argument more forcefully in the hope that it somehow gains substance (which, by the way, it didn't).

Comment: Here is the solution to the simultanous $3x^{2} -y^{2} =2 (1); 8x^{2} -z^{2} =7 (2)$   $ x(n+1) =2x(n) +y(n); y(n+1) =3x(n) +2y(n) $ for (1) and $ x(n+1) = 3x(n) +z(n); z(n+1) = 8x(n) +3z(n)$ for (2). And we get $(1,1);(3,5);(11,19) and (-1,1);(2,5);(11,31)$ The solutions coincide in the same n-th position, the third position: for the *only* solution (x,y,z) = (11,19,31)

Comment: Once you have found a match for the main variable, the one that is common to both equations, it is easy to determine in this case that one of the recurrences for the main variable values ,x, grows faster than the other and thus there will not be a coincidence again  happening in the same nth position for (x,y) and for (x,z). The only difficulty would be to find this coincidence if it was located in the, (say), 999887-th position, and this can be done easily by computers without the  need of any special algorithm at all. We do not need a special algorithm here.

Comment: There is another family of solutions for (2): $(1,1);(4,11);(23,65);(134,379);..$ that grows faster for both x and for z, after the second term, than the other family. And it grows also faster, after only the second term, for both x and z than respectively x and y in the solutions (x,y) Therefore we know there will not be a match again in the same k-th position where the solutions to the simultanous  system must be looked for. And we can affirm without need of special algorithm that (1,1,1) and (11,19,31) are **the only solutions** to this system of Pell like equations.

Comment: Consider the Pell equations $x^2 - 3z^2 = 1$; $y^2 - 783z^2 = 1$.  The first equation has solutions $(1,0); (2,1); (7,4), (26,15); \ldots$, and the second has solutions $(1,0); (28,1); (1567,56); (87724,3135)\ldots$.   The first two $z$ values match, but after that the second system grows much much faster.   Safe to say there are no more matches, right?

Comment: Yes Erick. What i am saying is the only two solutions to this simultanous Pell system are (x,y,z) = (1,1,0) and (2,28,1) because both solutions coincide at the same position (first position and second position), in the two sequences of solutions; and then one grows faster than the other one and will not match/coincide again for another solution.

Comment: Things would be different,though, and more difficult to deal with, if the values of the common variable in both sequences did coincide and match at distinct positions k-th and l-th in each sequence of solutions. Then we would not know, once we found this coincidence by a brute force search; if there were still more solutions or not; and we´ll need probably a good finite algorithm for finding all the solutions of the system.

Comment: I understand what your claim is.  Now consider the third solution $(x,y,z) = (97,1567,56)$.  I hope you'll take a close look at what Gerry Myerson told you, with a more open mind this time.

Comment: Ok, my mental algorithm was  wrong; i still have to think and try to understand why i mistook; I had thought what Gerry said, before he said it; but then i thought, the same position in which the coincidences ocurred was a sufficient guarantee; and then sorry for my mistake. I should work not in "real time" as i am doing, and also not as an amateur that never studied number theory and never properly mathematics nor physics and does not remember anything of the past, as i know some do.

Comment: @Erick, how you were able to resist writing GOTCHA!, I'll never know. Well done.

Comment: Mister Erick Wong. You tricked me choosing the two equations of the Middle, instead of the two right ones. Ingenious -and right and correct- as had been my statement of the unicity of the non trivial solution of my Pell-like system of equations without the need of further algorithms; i was extremely ingenuous -as a non expert amateur- to believe you were right.

Comment: We do have in fact 3 equations to the system  with 3 variables. The third is y^2 -261x^2 = -260 whose solutions are                                               (x,y) = (1,1); (2,28); (97,1567); (341,5509) and must be compared to                                                                                (z,y) = (0,1); (1,28); (56,1567); (3135,87724)

Comment: We clearly see comparing the y´s of one family to the y´s of the other; that the 3 solutions (x,y,z) = (1,1,0); (2,28,1); and (97, 1567,56) coincide in position and afterwards y grows faster in the (z,y) solutions, with the guarantee, therefore, there is not any more solutions to your system, without the need of any further work or algorithm.

Comment: Previously you tricked me by inducing me to compare two different variables: x with y , which is obviously absurd. I was right, but had to make a autocritic like in the times of Mao; you were not  a gentleman.

Comment: You can keep living in your fantasy world, or you can read the Szalay paper and actually learn some mathematics. Your choice.

Comment: Yes, a mere use of the great Legendre work and then of the great Thue work and finally you have to use a Magma computing package to solve the equations; i am not even certain that you could solve them with Pari gp. An algorithm for computers only is not a good algorithm.

Comment: An algorithm for computers that gives correct answers beats an algorithm for humans that gives incorrect ones.

Comment: Gold is not bad; but platinum or happiness is better. Using an algorithm that works with too many steps is fine; finding a simpler algorithm is better. Lewis in anyland staded it: a clock that is slow (or fast) 1 minute/day is worse than a clock that does not work -but indicates the exact hour twice in a day- since you have to wait 60*12= 720 days = almost 2 years for the first clock to give the correct time. The more precise the clock is, worse is the case. If the slow or fast is 1 second/day     you´ll have to wait 118 years for your clock to indicate correctly the time.

Comment: Though my memory is far from good i clearly remember when i was an adolescent and read the Carroll clock story, i was unable to concentrate my mind -they had altered it- enough a time to be able to confirm by a calculation of my own, the almost 2 years period for the clock to be accurate again. They clearly controlled my mind at times and still do at times. But now i know it and try to say it; for  innocents must not be considered guilty just because they (I) were (was) absolutely unable to defend themselves (himself).