# System of two Pell's equations that might have infinitely many solutions

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

Does there exist infinitely many integers $(a,b,c)$ verifying simultaneously the two following equations:
$$a^2-2b^2=-1$$ and
$$a^2-24c^2=1$$

Well I tried this problem with Pell's equation approach $a=7$ and $c=2$ (for the 2nd equation) be the initial solution but it's really very hard for me to predict such $(a,b)$
Any help is appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

Note that we can make the substitution,
$a=u^2+12v^2$ and $b=u^2-12v^2$ from the equation $$a^2=b^2+12c^2$$ Now plug this in $a^2-2b^2=-1$ we have the following
$$u^4-72u^2v^2+144v^2-1=0$$ by Quadratic formula we have , $$u=\sqrt{36v^2+\sqrt{1152v^4+1}}$$ to be pairs $(u,v)$ in integers, Thus we need infinitely many $v$ so that
$$\sqrt{36v^2+\sqrt{1152v^4+1}}\in\mathbb{Z}_{> 1}$$
Any progress from here.

Comment: For the second equation, note $a = 7$ and $c = 2$ gives $a^2 - 24c^2 = 49 - 24(4) = -47$. Instead, $a = 5$ and $c = 1$ works properly.

Comment: I need for both to be true.

Comment: Then you should look for "simultaneous Pell equations". There are many posts, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033171/does-this-system-of-simultaneous-pell-like-equations-have-any-non-trivial-positi), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281902/solving-a-system-of-pell-and-pell-like-equations).

Comment: If a is the same unknown in the two equations, then you can write $a^2=2b^2-1=24c^2 +1$ from which you get $2b^2 - 24c^2 = 2$ or $b^2 -12c^2=1$, just another Pell equation with only one solution $(7,2)$ for $b,c$.

Comment: @user25406 in that case a is not a perfect square btw if this that infinitely namy solution it can disprove Fermats Catalan conjecture

Comment: @ThePhoenix I think you mean only finitely many ***integer*** points. Kindly see [Siegel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_theorem_on_integral_points).